# Video not recording properly using mediarecorder

Tags: java, android, video, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I was making an app to record video with audio and save it to the **SD card**.            And it records very well, but when video plays, the audio output was great but the video was not captured properly.

> **below is screenshot of video when i played it :-**[image: This is image of video screenshot that i recorded with my app]

> Here is the code

```
public class BroadcastScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Camera camera;
FrameLayout live;
protected CameraPreview preview;
protected FileManager manager;
protected MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.broadcast);

    live = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_live);
    Button capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butPicture);
    Button video = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butVideo);

    capture.setOnClickListener(this);
    video.setOnClickListener(this);

    manager = new FileManager(this);

    if (checkCameraHardware()) {

        camera = getCamera();
        if (camera != null) {
            preview = new CameraPreview(this, camera);
            live.addView(preview);
        } else {
            showError("Error in opening camera");
        }

    }
}

public static Camera getCamera() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return c;
}

private boolean setupVideoRecorder() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    try {
        camera.unlock();

        mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);

        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(manager.setVideoFile(2).getPath());

        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(preview.getHolder().getSurface());

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        manager.saveAnyFile(data, 1);
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.startPreview();

    }

};

private boolean recording = false;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.butPicture:
        camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

        break;
    case R.id.butVideo:
        if (recording) {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            camera.lock();
            Button but = (Button) v;
            but.setText("Record");
            recording = false;
        } else if (!recording) {
            if (setupVideoRecorder()) {
                mediaRecorder.start();
                Button but = (Button) v;
                but.setText("Stop");
                recording = true;
            }
        } else {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
        }
        break;
    }
}

public boolean checkCameraHardware() {
    if (this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void showError(String error) {
    Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    // camera.startPreview();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaRecorder();
    releaseCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    // camera.release();
}

private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
        mediaRecorder.reset();
        mediaRecorder.release();
        mediaRecorder = null;
        camera.lock();
    }
}

private void releaseCamera() {
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}

}
```

> so i want to record video properly as the default camera app does..thanks for help
>   
>   
>   **Update:**
>   Ok i tested this app on other device and i dont know why but it works perfect video and audio both are fine but still its not working on my phone... i think maybe its because it not works on **Android 4.1.2** and because that other phone has **Android 5.1**....please guys help me its totally messed up.

Comment: did you run the code on other devices ?

Comment: yes ofcourse i run it ...

Comment: how can i able to know without running it